# How can I build up an ActiveRecord query incrementally, line by line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I'd like to piece together an ActiveRecord query using runtime data. What I have in mind is something like...

```
r = Person.where('last_name LIKE ?', foo)
r.where('created_at < ?', Time.now - 100.days)
r.where( ...some other conditions... )
```

That doesn't work as intended though. To get it to work you have to chain them together all on one line...

```
Person.where('last_name LIKE ?', foo) \
  .where('created_at < ?', Time.now - 100.days) \
  .where( ...some other conditions... )
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to spread it over separate operations on multiple lines.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) methods (like `.where`) return a new object. So you just have to hold on to it. See:

```
r = Person.where('last_name LIKE ?', foo)
r = r.where('created_at < ?', Time.now - 100.days)
r = r.where( ...some other conditions... )
```

Answer (score 2):

Arel frustratingly doesn't mutate the object or the underlying query when you call its methods.  But each method does return the Arel object, which allows the chaining.  You have to do:

```
r = Person.where(...
r = r.where('created_at...')
```

etc., etc.

Comment: I treat it as a feature rather than a bug :)

Comment: It *feels* different then how it ought to behave.  But maybe that's just me.  I have had issues before where I accidentally forgot to re-assign the variable after calling an arel method and was not getting the results I expected.  So... I call it frustrating :p

Comment: Ideally it would support a bang variant for mutating, ie `r.where! 'created_at ...'`